# Getting current_user undefined method while using devise gem - Ruby on Rails 4.1.5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm following tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7-1HCWbu7iU
I already did Pintrest clone using devise gem and had no issue. When I try to add current_user to links controller I get "undefined method current_user". I tried everything... even redoing the app from scratch, defining current_user, resetting the database. I guess the gem should handle the method automatically, right?

Here are my steps:

```
1. Generate new app - rails new raddit
2. Generate scaffold: rails g scaffold link title:string url:string
3. rake db:migrate
4. add gem 'devise', '~> 3.3.0' to gem file and run bundle install
5. run rails g devise:install
6. add file to development.rb - config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
7. add alerts to layout/application.html (as per devise documentation)
8. generate view file - rails g devise:views
9. generate user - rails g devise User
10. rake db:migrate
11. rails s
12. go to localhost:3000/users/sign_up (works ok)
13. Add relation to models: user.rb - has_many :links ; link.rb -   belongs_to :user
14. Create migration: rails generate migration add_user_id_to_links user_id:integer:index
15. rake db:migrate
16. go to rails console and save assocation between user and links.
17. Add current_user to links controller - Getting undefined 'curren_user method' once I go to localhost:3000/links/new
```

Here is my code:

```
  class LinksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_link, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
     @links = Link.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @link = Link.current_user.links.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @link = current_user.build(link_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @link.save
        format.html { redirect_to @link, notice: 'Link was       successfully created.' }
         format.json { render :show, status: :created, location:  @link }
      else
         format.html { render :new }
         format.json { render json: @link.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end


  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @link.update(link_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @link, notice: 'Link was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @link }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @link.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
       @link.destroy
       respond_to do |format|
       format.html { redirect_to links_url, notice: 'Link was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private

    def set_link
      @link = Link.find(params[:id])
    end

   def link_params
      params.require(:link).permit(:title, :url)
   end
   end
```

My models: link.rb

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

My models: user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :links
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting the undefined method 'current_user' in the new action where you are calling Link.current_user.

```
def new
  @link = Link.current_user.links.build
end
```

should be

```
def new
  @link = current_user.links.build
end
```

Link does not have a current_user method, that is the problem.  current_user is defined in the context of the controller and should be used as you do in the create action.

Answer (score 0):

it should be

@link = current_user.links.build

in new action

if you have more problem than just type exit in new action and check the current_user in console..  You can get errors from console.. so every time check your console first.

use better_errors gem.. for more info about the particular error

Comment: Oh shoot... yes, that was the root of the problem. I fixed it myself without realising lol. But now you told me what fixed it. I should be more vigilant.